# How to export an EC private key from p12

Tags: openssl

I have a p12 store. I have read about export like this `openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.key.pem -nocerts -nodes` but it doesn't export in EC format.

How do I do I use openssl to export the private key in EC format?

I read that the exported key should begin with `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----`

Comment: Are you sure your .p12 contains an EC key? If you were able to successfully export a private key, and it called itself an RSA or DSA private key, then that's what kind of key you have inside that .p12. You can't "convert" an RSA or DSA key to EC; they're completely separate algorithms based on completely different math. It's not like they're just big random numbers that you can choose to use with any algorithm you'd like.

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I determine that?

Comment: Well if the command you wrote in your Question created a .pem file that just says "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" without specifying the type, you could try using `openssl ec -in newfile.key.pem -text` to see if it's parsable as an EC key. If it says it can't load the key, change the subcommand from `ec` to `rsa` in my command, to see if it parses as RSA. If that still fails, change the subcommand to `dsa`. One of those should work.

Comment: The rsa version of the command worked . Do I need to go through some steps to convert it to ec now? rsa -> der -> ec?

Comment: It is mathematically impossible to convert an RSA key to an EC key. They are based on completely different underlying mathematical principles. If you need an EC-based key pair, you'll need to generate an EC-based key pair from scratch. It won't be in any way related to your current RSA key pair in your current .p12, because EC and RSA are based on completely separate mathematical algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that your key is in fact an EC key, you are halfway there.

Once exported the key with

```
 openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -nodes -nocerts -out newfile.key.pem
```

then convert it to EC PRIVATE KEY using below command

```
openssl ec -in newfile.key.pem -out ec.key.pem
```

More info [here](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/export-certificates-private-key-from-pkcs12-file-with-openssl/#ftoc-heading-6)